# How to fix ngon shading issues in angled ceiling?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, shaders, vertices

I am new to 3D modelling, so please go easy on me :-)
What would be best practice to deal with the ceiling to prevent shading issues as it is an ngon? I tried to triangulate the shape, but this deforms it and creates gaps between ceiling and walls..

[image: screenshot of geometry, highlighting the ceiling of interest]

[image: ceiling appears bulgy]

Project file:
https://we.tl/t-mHIyXSnMUn

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: make sure your ceiling is planar

Comment: @moonboots Added a link to the project file in the main post now.

Comment: @Raildex That's the challenge! The ceiling is not planar because of the fixed height of the walls which need to stay as they are, so I can't change this.

Comment: what shading issue are you talking about, could you please add an image that highlights the problem?

Comment: @moonboots I added a screenshot with a uv checker now, you can see it appears very bulgy. I am curious how to model a ceiling like this in a good way?

Comment: @UlfsenUlf That depends on what kind of ceiling you want to have... if the walls have to stay as they are, you simply cannot have a completely straight planar ceiling, because the corner vertices do not all lie in the same plane. You said you tried triangulating but you didn't like that. What do you want instead? A curved concave ceiling? Or convex? Or horizontal planes with some kind of connections between the different height levels?

Comment: If the walls need to remain the same height, the question is off-topic, since it has nothing to do with using Blender, but instead is interior design decision. It is very rare to have ceiling that is curved, unless that's a specific interior feature. In most cases most interior designers would probably find a way to flatten the ceiling. that is most likely possible because of the way buildings tend to be built.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I think I will have to triangulate it somehow after all. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should model the ceiling realistically so that it would be possible in reality. At the moment it is not planar so you either need to make it planar or you need to divide it so it has some edges between planar parts something like this:

[image]

One good way to keep angled ceiling flat would be to use a separate plane that defines the angle and Shrinkwrap modifier set to Project mode in Z axis. You would need to put top vertices of the walls to a separate vertex group to only affect the top:

[image]

This way you can easily adjust the position of the walls if needed:

[image]

Other way it becomes quite an unnecessarily complex task to if you need changes later.

In the unlikely scenario of actually curved ceiling, you could crease the edges(Ctrl+E -> 1) making corners of your walls, connect every point of the ceiling that would make concave shapes(those will not produce good results) and use Subdivision Surface modifier:

[image]

You would probably want to apply the modifier at some point and delete the unnecessary geometry in the walls.